# Could not load file or assembly 'JetEntityFrameworkProvider'

Tags: wpf, ms-access, entity, oledb

I have a problem with JetEntityFrameworkProvider?

My App.config Codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework"
      type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
      requirePermission="false"/>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings"
      type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="mrgame.Properties.Settings"
        type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="mrgame.Properties.Settings"
        type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
        allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnectionString"
         connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\projects\desktop\MrGame\MrGame\bin\Debug\Data\database.accdb;"
         providerName="JetEntityFreamworkProvider"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"/>
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb"/>
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
      <provider invariantName="JetEntityFrameworkProvider" type="JetEntityFrameworkProvider.JetProviderServices, JetEntityFrameworkProvider"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="JetEntityFrameworkProvider"/>
      <add invariant="JetEntityFrameworkProvider" name="Jet Entity Framework Provider" description="Jet Entity Framework Provider"
        type="JetEntityFrameworkProvider.JetProviderFactory, JetEntityFrameworkProvider"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

and My DBContextClass is:

```
class AppContext : DbContext
    {

        public AppContext() : base("DefaultConnectionString")
        {

        }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }


        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
    }
```

But when I run my project I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'JetEntityFrameworkProvider' or one of its dependencies. An attempt
>   was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

I removed JetEntityFrameworkProvider and reinstall by NuGet but It throw exception..